# Use IP Tables to route all the traffic from one port through another

Tags: iptables

I am using digitalocean account and a non sudo user.

My current port is `8090`

What i want is using iptables i could access 8090 http data by requesting from port 80

For more clearly. I am non sudo user

In development i have started my server at port 8090. Now want to run it on `80` so that visiting user should not include port number along with my domain name

**What is now**

```
http://www.site.tk:8090/
```

**What I Want**

```
http://www/site.tk/
```

PS: I can use non sudo ports only

Comment: you can use iptable forwarding `sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8090` but you must use **sudo** with **80** port, because the first 1024 ports are restricted to the root user only.

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire I wont use sudo, but my system admin will do ..
Anyways thanks for your help

Comment: Also tell me how to reset this ? or in simple words how do i destroy this rule ??

Comment: you can read this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules